# Where can I find MySql.Data.Cf.dll in MySQL Connectors?

Tags: .net, mysql, smartphone

I have downloaded MySQL Connector .NET 6.4.2 and installed it on my system for Smart Device Programs. However, I can't find `MySql.Data.Cf.dll` among the files installed.

I only have `MySql.Data.dll`, `MySql.Data.Entity.dll` and `MySql.Web.dll` in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.4.2\Assemblies\v4.0` and `and C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.4.2\Assemblies\v2.0`.

Where can I find `MySql.Data.Cf.dll` in MySQL Connectors?

Comment: You can't. See http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62067 but effectively you need 6.4.4 or later. This got me too! Downloads are here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: Are you affected the missingmanifestresourceexception?

Comment: Nope; but this can be connection string dependent - I think we had to put ;pooling=false on the end of our connection string to fix this - at least that's what the checkin comment suggests. When are you getting the exception?

Comment: I just import MySql.Data.Cf.dll in another project which is download from web. that i am not install MySqlConnector 6.4.4 or MySqlConnect0r 6.3.8.

Now i install the MySqlConnect0r 6.4.4, now i got new error,..Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Comment: my connection string is server=192.168.1.100;database=mcubic;User Name=mcubic;Password=mcs@2011$;pooling=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - this is a [publicly acknowledged bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62067).

You can download the fixed versions:

- [MySqlConnector 6.4.4](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)
- [MySqlConnect0r 6.3.8](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.3.html#downloads)

Installing either of these puts MySql.Data.CF.dll in (on a 64-bit machine):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net X.Y.Z\Assemblies\v2.0
```